# How to avoid first Character value is “-“from the Word entered in the Input box

Tags: javascript, html

I need to avoid only first character value is `-` symbol in text box.

```
$(document).on("keypress", "#form_name", function() {
  if ($('#form_name').val().substr(0, 1) == "-") {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
});
```

I am trying this method it is not working properly.

Kindly guide me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#form_name", function() { //when a user types in input box
    var formValue = this.value;
    if ( formValue.charAt( 0 ) == '-' ) {
         return false;
    } else {
         return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to swap what you have given:

```js
$(document).on("keyup", "#form_name", function() {
  if ($('#form_name').val().substr(0, 1) == "-") {
    $('#form_name').val("");
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="form_name" />
```

I have also added a small error message with this. Check it out:

```js
$(".error").hide();
$(document).on("keyup", "#form_name", function() {
  if ($('#form_name').val().substr(0, 1) == "-") {
    $('#form_name').val("");
    $(this).next(".error").fadeIn();
    return false;
  } else
    $(this).next(".error").fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.error {display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid #f00; background: #f66; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; font-size: 0.8em; border-radius: 3px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="form_name" />
<span class="error">Cannot start with -.</span>
```